# How to create an instance of an object type from parent document inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, iframe, document

I have an iframe like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myLib.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe>
            <script>
                /***CEATE NEW OBJECT HERE***/
                new MyObject();
            </script>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I want to create new object form most parent inside iframe. 
How can do it?
I try to use ***window.top*** on this format :

```
new window.top.MyObject();
```

but I get this error :

*Uncaught Error: no element is specified to initialize MyObject*

Comment: Can you provide some more details as to why you need to do this from within an iFrame? What you want to do is technically possible however the way in which you intend to use the iFrame will heavily impact how feasible it is

Answer (score 0):

iframe are used to embed another html doc not for any including html tags and element. For reference please check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe